# Use AppleScript to Duplicate a File to a Different Folder with a New Name

Tags: duplicates, applescript, move

I am attempting to duplicate a file to a specified folder but I get an error:

> error "Finder got an error: Can’t set file \"/Users/Andrew/Documents/Finances/Statements - Bank And Credit Card CSVs/2020-05-01 April 2020 Report/Steps/2020-05-01 April 2020 BEFORE STEP 01.xlsm\" to file \"/Users/Andrew/Documents/Finances/Budget Reports/2020-05-01 April 2020.xlsm\"." number -10006 from file "/Users/Andrew/Documents/Finances/Statements - Bank And Credit Card CSVs/2020-05-01 April 2020 Report/Steps/2020-05-01 April 2020 BEFORE STEP 01.xlsm"

I have to use AppleScript because I am initiating the script from within VBA. the part of the AppleScript that determines the 3 variables works as intended. For brevity the code looks like this:

```
DuplicateFileToStepsFolder("/Users/Andrew/Documents/Finances/Budget Reports/2020-05-01 April 2020.xlsm!/Users/Andrew/Documents/Finances/Statements - Bank And Credit Card CSVs/2020-05-01 April 2020 Report/Steps!BEFORE STEP 01")

on DuplicateFileToStepsFolder(ReportAndStepsPaths)

    --code to split ReportAndStepsPaths into separate strings

    set BudgetReportPath to "/Users/Andrew/Documents/Finances/Budget Reports/2020-05-01 April 2020.xlsm" --this is the file i want to duplicate
    set StepsFolderPath to "/Users/Andrew/Documents/Finances/Statements - Bank And Credit Card CSVs/2020-05-01 April 2020 Report/Steps" --this is the directory I want to duplicate (or copy and move to)
    set BudgetReportStepPath to "/Users/Andrew/Documents/Finances/Statements - Bank And Credit Card CSVs/2020-05-01 April 2020 Report/Steps/2020-05-01 April 2020 BEFORE STEP 01.xlsm" --this is the new file name

    tell application "Finder" to duplicate file BudgetReportPath to folder StepsFolderPath
    --line to rename the moved file would go here
end DuplicateFileToStepsFolder
```

Copy, move and rename would also solve my problem. I haven't tried to figure out the rename line. I am sure that there are no file name collisions either.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the Finder doesn't support POSIX paths (slash separated).

Either you convert everything to HFS paths (colon separated) with `POSIX file` or you use HFS paths anyway.

This is the HFS path version which specifies the base folder "Finances" with a relative `path to`

```
set financesFolder to (path to documents folder as text) & "Finances:"

set BudgetReportFile to financesFolder & "Budget Reports:2020-05-01 April 2020.xlsm"
set StepsFolderPath to financesFolder & "Statements - Bank And Credit Card CSVs:2020-05-01 April 2020 Report:Steps:"
set BudgetReportStepName to "2020-05-01 April 2020 BEFORE STEP 01.xlsm"

tell application "Finder"
    set duplicatedFile to duplicate file BudgetReportFile to folder StepsFolderPath
    set name of duplicatedFile to BudgetReportStepName
end tell
```